# random lines with delay in between

Tags: bash

I am using the following package to pull random lines from file(s) where line delimiter is %
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rl.1.html

```
rl -c 10 -d % myfile.txt
```

-c 10 gives 10 lines as output.

How can I force it to sleep for some specified amount of time after each line it prints?

Answer (score 2):

From reading the man page, it seems that there is no such option built into `rl`, so you will have to use something else to achieve that. For example, you can do it with `for`:

```
for i in `seq 10`; do rl -c 1 -d % myfile.txt; sleep 5; done
```

That will make it "sleep" for 5 seconds between each execution. Note that `-c` option is now `1`. This way, there is the risk that the same line might be selected twice within the 10 repetitions. Another way to do the same thing without that risk is:

```
rl -c 10 -d % myfile.txt | while read line; do echo $line; sleep 5; done
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with loops and as you said, indeed it was repeating. Now rl particularly takes care that it does not repeat for -c 10. Your second method is what I was looking for.

Comment: This method is not recognizing the delimiter. :(

Comment: @cosmicraga If it also outputs the lines with % as terminator, then you have to tell read to use % instead of newline as well. `while IFS= read -rd % line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; sleep 5; done < <(rl -c10 -d% myfile.txt)`. Also see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/026 for other ways to pick random lines from a file.